# How can I find the points of intersection of $f(x)=\sin(\sqrt{x^2+4})$ and $g(x)=4-x^2$ analytically

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, functions

How can I find the points of intersection of $f(x)=\sin(\sqrt{x^2+4})$ and $g(x)=4-x^2$ analytically without having to resort to a graph? Thank you very much

I know that $-1\leq\sin(\sqrt{x^2+4})\leq 1$, with which $-1\leq4-x^2\leq 1$ and $-1\leq (2-x)(2+x)\leq 1$, but I do not know what else to do, could you help me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

HINT: write your equation in the form
$$\sin\left(\sqrt{x^2+4}\right)-(4-x^2)=0$$ and use a numerical method.
this can not be done analytically!
$$x\approx -1.90515677885686969692$$
$$x\approx 1.90515677885686969692$$

Answer (score 3):

**Dr. Sonnhard Graubner**'s answer shows how we can get a numerical solution to the problem. With a lot of problems like this, it's difficult, if even possible to get an analytic solution. In fact this particular problem is very similar to finding [Dottie's number](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/DottieNumber.html). But we might be able to get a closed form solution as follows:

$$x=\sqrt{\left(\pi+\frac{8-\pi^2}{\pi}+\ldots\right)^2-4} \quad\sim1.905\ldots$$

As shown by **Barry Cipra**, we can use the substitution $u=\sqrt{x^2+4}$ to show that the problem is equivalent to solving $\sin(u)+u^2-8=0$. Define $f(u)=\sin(u)+u^2-8$, so the problem becomes a root-finding problem for $f(u)=0$. Since the root is $2.762\approx\pi$ can construct a series for the root at $u=\pi$, knowing that $f(\pi)=\pi^2-8$. We can use the Lagrange Inversion Theorem to create an inverse function for $f$ as follows:

$$\begin{aligned}
\\&f^{-1}(w)=\pi+\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{g_n[w-(\pi^2-8)]^n}{n!}
\\&\text{where}\quad g_n=\lim_{w\to0}\frac{\mathrm{d}^{n-1}}{\mathrm{d}w^{n-1}}\left(\frac{w-\pi}{\sin(w)+w^2-\pi^2}\right)^n
\end{aligned}$$

## Computation of $g_n$

The previous equation gives the possibility of an analytic solution, but it's contingent on finding a closed form for the $g_n$ without limits or derivatives. I've computed the first few values for the first few $g_n$, which are in the table below. It's pretty clear that each $g_n$ is a rational function in $\pi$, with integer coefficients. But what are these coefficients? Maybe you can find a pattern in the coefficients! With OEIS.org, we can look up the sequence of integers not multiplied by $\pi$, in the numerator of each $g_n$. I.e. the sequence $(1,2,12,120,1680,30240\ldots)$, we find that these are the "quadruple factorial numbers" (https://oeis.org/A001813). Maybe this trend continues?

$$\begin{array}{|c|c|c|}
\hline
n & g_n & g_n \quad\text{(approx.)} \\
\hline
1 & 1/\pi & 0.318\ldots \\
\hline
2 & ^{(2-2\pi)}/_{\pi^4}& -0.044\ldots \\
\hline
3 & ^{6(2-3\pi+2\pi^2)}/_{\pi^7}& 0.0245\ldots \\
\hline
4 & ^{-4(-30+60\pi-66\pi^2+60\pi^3+\pi^4)}/_{\pi^{10}}& -0.0228\ldots \\
\hline
5 & ^{20(84-210\pi+306\pi^2-240\pi^3+78\pi^4+5\pi^5)}/_{\pi^{13}}& 0.0285\ldots \\
\hline
\end{array}$$

$$\begin{aligned}
\\f^{-1}(0)
&=\pi+\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{g_n}{n!}(8-\pi^2)^n
\\&=\pi+\frac1\pi(8-\pi^2)+\frac{(2-2\pi)(8-\pi^2)^2}{2\pi^4}+\ldots
\\x&=\sqrt{f^{-1}(0)^2-4}
\\
\\x&=\sqrt{\left(\pi+\frac{8-\pi^2}{\pi}+\ldots\right)^2-4}
\end{aligned}$$

## Assumptions and Possible Patterns

#### Assumption 1

The power of $\pi$ in the denominator of each $g_n$ appears to be $3n-2$, and the power of $\pi$ in the numerator seems to be less than the numerator, which would suggest that the sum is of the form:

$$\begin{aligned}
\\f^{-1}(0)
&=\pi+\sum_{n=1}^\infty\sum_{i=0}^{3n-2} \frac{(8-\pi^2)^n\pi^{i-(3n-2)}}{n!}a_{i,n}
\end{aligned}$$

Where $a_{i,n}$ is a sequence of integers.

#### Assumption 2

If we also assume, as we noted before, that $a_{0,n}$ are the quadruple factorial numbers, $\frac{(2n)!}{n!}$ then we can group together all of the terms in the numerator that aren't multiplied by $\pi$ and form a convergent series with them as follows:
$$\begin{aligned}
\\f^{-1}(0)
&=\pi+\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(8-\pi^2)^n\pi^{-(3n-2)}}{n!}\frac{(2n)!}{n!}+\sum_{n=1}^\infty\sum_{i=1}^{3n-2}\ldots
\\&=\pi+\pi^2\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(8-\pi^2)^n(2n)!}{\pi^{3n}(n!)^2}+\ldots
\\&=\pi+\pi^2\frac{\pi^{3/2}-s}{s}+\ldots
\end{aligned}$$

Where $s=\sqrt{-32+4\pi^2+\pi^3}$.

#### Assumption 3

We can also look at the sequence of $a_{1,n}$, i.e. $(0,-2,-18,-240,\ldots)$, and note that for each of them, $\frac{a_{1,n}}{a_{0,n}}=\frac{n-1}{2}$. Assuming this trend continues that assumption 2 is true, then:

$$\begin{aligned}
\\f^{-1}(0)
&=\ldots+\pi^2\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(8-\pi^2)^n(2n)!}{\pi^{3n}(n!)^2}\frac{(n-1)}{2}+\sum_{n=1}^\infty\sum_{i=2}^{3n-2}\ldots
\\&=\ldots+\frac{\pi^2(48\pi^{3/2}-6\pi^{7/2}-\pi^{9/2}+s^3)}{2s^3}+\ldots
\\&=2.205\;877\ldots+\sum_{n=1}^\infty\sum_{i=2}^{3n-2}\ldots
\end{aligned}$$

## Graph of Inverse Function

To illustrate my answer, the figure below is what the inverted function, $f^{-1}$, looks like (in red), up to the $5$th degree, with $g_n$ to $3$ decimal places. Note that it is very nearly the mirror of the function, $f$, (in blue), when reflected in the green line, $y=x$. Since the root we're interested in is where $f$ crosses the $x$-axis, we can find it with $f^{-1}(0)$, where $f^{-1}$ crosses the $y$-axis. Note also that this approximation only works for $x\approx\pi$ but doesn't work for $x$ outside of this interval.

[image: inverted series]

Answer (score 2):

Let $u=\sqrt{x^2+4}$.  Then $x^2=u^2-4$, so the equation to solve becomes

$$\sin u=8-u^2$$

with $u$ understood to be positive.  Since $|\sin u|\le1$, there is a solution $u\in[\sqrt7,3]$, which corresponds to $|x|\in[\sqrt3,\sqrt5]$.  But the equation has no nice closed-form solution; your best bet is a numerical approximation.

One way to get an approximation is by iterating the recursion

$$u_{n+1}=\sqrt{8-\sin u_n}$$

starting say with $u_n=3$.  This leads to $u\approx2.762177$, or $x\approx1.90516$.

Comment: Should be specified that  $u=\sqrt{8-\sin u}$ is a contraction mapping on all intervals because $u'(x)<1$ for any $x\in \mathbb{R}$ so that the fixed point theorem can be applied

Answer (score 1):

*Just to add a few things after Jam's answer.*

Sooner or later, you will learn than, better than with Taylor expansions, functions can be approximated using [Padé approximants](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pad%C3%A9_approximant) which, built around $u=u_0$, are in the form of $$f(u)=\frac{\sum_{i=0}^m a_i (u-u_0)^i } {1+\sum_{i=1}^n b_i (u-u_0)^i}$$ Using, for simplicity, $m=1$, this gives as an approximate solution $$u_{(n)}=u_0-\frac{a_0^{(n)}}{a_1^{(n)}}$$ (remember that $a_0$ and $a_1$ depend on the degree $n$ used for the denominator).

Applying the method to $f(u)=\sin(u)+u^2-8$ with $u_0=\pi$, we could obtain
$$\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
  n & u_{(n)} & \text{approx} \\
 0 & \frac{8-\pi +\pi ^2}{2 \pi -1} & 2.78771 \\
 1 & \frac{-8+25 \pi -3 \pi ^2+\pi ^3}{9-4 \pi +3 \pi ^2} & 2.76231 \\
 2 & \frac{432-230 \pi +318 \pi ^2-52 \pi ^3+6 \pi ^4+\pi ^5}{-38+228 \pi -76 \pi
   ^2+24 \pi ^3+\pi ^4} & 2.76208 \\
 3 & \frac{-1824+13380 \pi -5628 \pi ^2+3612 \pi ^3-600 \pi ^4+24 \pi ^5+18 \pi
   ^6}{2436-2208 \pi +3828 \pi ^2-1104 \pi ^3+168 \pi ^4+24 \pi ^5} & 2.76218
\end{array}
\right)$$